# Creating a Dynamic view with spinner Dependable in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, view, spinner

I have an issue of loading view dynamically. I have three dynamic spinner view when i select first item from the spinner it should create a text view above second spinner but its creating a view below third spinner. Can any one guide me how to achieve it.I have shared my code below.

```
/add LayoutParams
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rl.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


        // add spinner

        String[] spinnerArray = {"Android","ios","other"};
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);


        String[] spinnerArray1 = {"flowers","vegetables","other"};
        Spinner spinner1 = new Spinner(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray1); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
        spinnerArrayAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter1);



        String[] spinnerArray2 = {"cat","dog","other"};
        Spinner spinner2 = new Spinner(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray2); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
        spinnerArrayAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter2);


        rl.addView(spinner);
        rl.addView(spinner1);
        rl.addView(spinner2);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
             if(position==1)
             {
                 TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                 tv.setText("Hello");
                 rl.addView(tv);
             }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how LinearLayout works? 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html
You should call

```
addView(tv, 1);
```

Specifying position on where to insert view.